# "Too Many Input Arguments"

Tags: matlab

Exact error is:

```
Error using symengine>@()0.0
Too many input arguments.

Error in bdipuniodefun (line 18)
bdip = [s(4); s(5); s(6); (q/m_e)*(Ex(s(1),s(2),s(3)) + s(5)*Bz(s(1),s(2),s(3)) - s(6)*By(s(1),s(2),s(3))); (q/m_e)*(Ey(s(1),s(2),s(3)) +
s(6)*Bx(s(1),s(2),s(3)) - s(4)*Bz(s(1),s(2),s(3))); (q/m_e)*(Ez(s(1),s(2),s(3)) + s(4)*By(s(1),s(2),s(3)) - s(5)*Bx(s(1),s(2),s(3)))];

Error in odearguments (line 90)
f0 = feval(ode,t0,y0,args{:});   % ODE15I sets args{1} to yp0.

Error in ode15s (line 150)
    odearguments(FcnHandlesUsed, solver_name, ode, tspan, y0, options, varargin);

Error in collisions6 (line 219)
        [T,S] = ode15s(@bdipuniodefun, tspan, icv);
```

So we know where the error occurs, but I have been unable to resolve it nonetheless. This is an error that has also been inconsistent too. It does not always appear when I run the main script "collisions.m" but happens only when certain things get altered. Some examples: I start with too many electrons/particles, usually 1000+. Or I try to input a non-zero electric field. The electric field function is still being referenced but it is zero (Here comes the strange part). The reason I did this is because although the error goes away, the ode solver does not compute even close to the correct solutions I am looking for. I know for a fact that the results are wrong due to my knowledge of physics. However, when it does this, it does not give an error.

A Matlab staff member suggested that it may have something to due with my persistent variable definition but that is the only possible lead I have.

Troubleshooting methods I have already been through:

1. First if you look at the documentation from [Matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode15s.html), it shows a specific syntax example to define the set of ODEs. In Matlab's syntax, they define each equation individually and then the vector of equations using the definitions. When I tried this syntax, the solver either did not solve the equations correctly, or it gave me the "too many input arguments" error. The way I made it run at all was to define every equation outright on a single line in "bdipodefun.m". Only that syntax worked and there is no good reason in my mind why this is the case because the definition that is used in one of the input arguments for the solver is the same. Using the Matlab recommended syntax even in simpler code, makes the ode solution incorrect.
2. I tried all ode solvers Matlab has to offer. The same issues persist or it cannot solve the equations at all.
3. I tried re-coding the entire simulation from scratch. I have found that this error still occurs even in more simpler codes.
4. Equation solver will also not solve the system correctly if there is no E-field. I found that if I create an E-field function and even just define it as zero within the file, the system solves correctly. It absolutely makes no sense as to why this is occurring.

Here is a description of what each file does in the code:

- "collisionsmain.m" = Main script that references other files
- "B_test.m" = B field function file referenced by collisionsmain
- "E_test.m" = E field function file referenced by collisionsmain
- "engen.m" = Generates energies for electrons based on a Maxwellian probability distribution curve
- "maxdis.m" = Maxwellian distribution function used by engen
- "engen.m" = Generates energies for electrons based on a Maxwellian
- "posgen.m" = Generates a random, initial position on a sphere "bdipodefun.m" = ODE function set referenced by ODE solver in collisionsmain

Link to files: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/19eJrgWYL4LQFwTY-VwguCCkta-pimZlL?usp=sharing

Comment: “I have found that this error still occurs even in more simpler codes.” This is usually the case. You should create the simplest, shortest program that produces the error, then post that here instead of your original code. This is called a [mre] (read the link) and is useful to figure out why the error occurs. As it is, your question is off-topic for SO because it doesn’t contain a MRE and the code is not in the question itself.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I will look for it again and post it

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand the code because it is complicated and big. Anyway, I tracked the error and find the source of the issue. The error comes from the number of parameters that have been sent to `Ex, Ey, Ez` in `bdipuniodefun.m` function. `Ex, Ey, Ez` functions receives 3 parameters while they can handle one parameter only.

The following code didn't send error and it shows the results.

```
bdip_r1 = [s(4); s(5); s(6)];
bdip_r2 = (q/m_e) * (Ex(s(1)) + s(5)*Bz(s(1),s(2),s(3))- s(6)*By(s(1),s(2),s(3)));
bdip_r3 = (q/m_e)*(Ey(s(1)) + s(6)*Bx(s(1),s(2),s(3)) - s(4)*Bz(s(1),s(2),s(3)));
bdip_r4 = (q/m_e)*(Ez(s(1)) + s(4)*By(s(1),s(2),s(3)) - s(5)*Bx(s(1),s(2),s(3)));

bdip =[bdip_r1;bdip_r2;bdip_r3;bdip_r4];
```